# Fill table in Async way

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, html-table

I have a table with a lot of data. I would get these data from server row by row with async requests. On every response I would fill the table with a new row. In this way the user should be able to see the table filling step by step and not in one time. The request is by name and by date. So, that's an example I've done so far:

```
dataObj$: Observable<{}>;

this.allDates.forEach(date => {
            let timeStamp = moment(date).valueOf();
            this.dataObj$ = this.service.getData(userName, timeStamp);
        });
```

this is the result:

```
{"date":1593900000000,"done":12,"progress":30}
```

And this is the table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>

    </th>
    <th scope="col">
      Done
    </th>
    <th>
      Progress
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{(dataObj$ | async)?.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</th>
    <td>{{(dataObj$ | async)?.done}}</td>
    <td>{{(dataObj$ | async)?.progress}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this way I have a table with all dates in the first column, Done and Progress labels as headers and the other data to fill the rest of the table. Something like

```
      Done  Progress
data1  1       1    
data2  2       2    
data3  3       3
```

but it's not working like this actually. Right now the table is showing me just only the last row. What I want is different. It should show me that it creates row by row as soon as the request is finished. What's wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't you use loop to render table? `ngFor` to be specific

Comment: @Kenny what can i loop in this case? I mean, the response is a single object not an array. Do you have any idea how can i get the result I want? Also using ngFor if it works of course

Comment: @End.Game do you want the requests to be fired in parallel or sequential?

Comment: Sequential possibly. parallel could be a problem because there's a lot requests to fires. I think is the best way to do that. But if you have suggestions I'm glad to hear you

Comment: @End.Game best way would be to just get all the data :) or a date range and use pagination. But I can give you an answer with sequential rows

Comment: Thank you so much. I agree with you. But unfortunally I can't do that, someone else decided for me :) . I wait for your answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `concat` operator with the `scan` operator to combine all results:

```
interface DataObject {
  date: number;
  progress: number;
  dont: number;
}

readonly data$: Observable<DataObject[]> = concat(
  ...this.allDates.map((date) => this.service.getData(userName, moment(date).valueOf()))
).pipe(
  scan((dates, date) => {
    dates.push(date);

    return dates;
  }, [])
)

trackByDate(i: number, data: DataObject): number {
  return data.date;
}
```

Which you can use in your table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th scope="col">Done</th>
    <th>Progress</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of data$ | async; trackBy: trackByDate">
    <td>{{ data.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.done }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.progress }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-br8t5n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with mock request

Comment: I'm gonna try it. Thanks!

Comment: I can see al requests, so I think it's working, partially. It seems that all dates are undefined. I put a debugger to see this.allDates and it has all dates correctly. But it seems that inside the map operator something goes wrong..

Comment: If i put a debugger inside scan operator it doesn't stops. It doesn't go inside that

Comment: Well, it's working now but It calls 18 times per dates the service instead 1 :D

Comment: @End.Game I've updated my answer with a working example. I guess you implemented it wrong :)

Comment: Yeah I see.. my bad probably. I try to figure it out. Thank you so much